# SQL Server : SELECT with DISTINCT on variable multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to count the number of distinct items from this table but the distinct is over many columns stocked in a variable. This is 2 req.

Req 1:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT (CHECKSUM(code_paiement,id_emetteur,id_liaison)))
FROM [DB1].[dbo].[Vo_Fait]
```

Req 2:

```
declare @var nvarchar(4000) = 'code_paiement, id_emetteur, id_liaison'

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT (CHECKSUM(@var)))
FROM [DB1].[dbo].[Vo_Fait]
```

But the result of this 2 req is different !

- Result req 1 : 45205
- Result req 2 :     1

Comment: `distinct` is **not**  a function! Your second statements counts the number of distinct strings in the variable - which by definition is 1

Comment: in req 2 remove Distinct you will get same as req 1

Comment: I need to count the number of distinct items from this table but the distinct is over many columns stocked in a varibale.. if i remove Distinct i will have the count of all

Answer (score 1):

In "req2" you're taking the checksum of the string 'code_paiement,id_emetteur,id_liaison', which will always be the same, and counting the distinct values of it, which will always be 1.

Think of it this way: your code reduces to:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT (CHECKSUM('code_paiement,id_emetteur,id_liaison')))
FROM [DB1].[dbo].[Vo_Fait]
```

...which is the same as:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT (-1998057055))
FROM [DB1].[dbo].[Vo_Fait]
```

So you're counting the number of distinct occurrences of the number -1998057055 for every row in the table; as the value is the same for every row, there is only one distinct occurrence.

If you really need to build your SQL code dynamically (generally you should avoid this if possible by changing your design), then you should use something like `exec` or `sp_executesql`. A trivial example:

```
DECLARE @var NVARCHAR(4000) = 'code_paiement,id_emetteur,id_liaison';
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000)='SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(CHECKSUM(' + @var + '))) FROM [DB1].[dbo].[Vo_Fait]';
EXEC (@sql);
```

Comment: but i need to select count distinct from a variable !

Comment: Then you probably need to use dynamic SQL to build your statement. But in that case, it's probably a good time to take a step back and make sure you're really asking the right question, or solving your actual problem in the right way; dynamic SQL is generally something you should avoid.